# How to disable autocomplete for passwords in IE8 via GPO?

Tags: windows, internet-explorer-8, group-policy

In IE6 there was a registry key hidden away that would allow you to enable autocomplete but only for usernames, not passwords.

This key no longer has any effect in IE8.  I can either enable or disable autocomplete for usernames **and** passwords, but not just one of the two.

What I'm looking for is a way to enable autocomplete for usernames, but disable it for passwords.

Is there a way to do this in IE8?

Answer (score 2):

Seems that this isn't possible anymore ;(

https://serverfault.com/questions/27981/how-to-disable-autocomplete-for-passwords-in-ie8-via-gpo/27998